# Initializing the browsers default auto-suggest for inputs added after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load the inputs through jQuery programatically I don't get any autosuggest values (that previously stored/used in the browser) but will show suggestions when not loaded programatically.  For example:

```
<input name=color/>
```

Should show me all previously inputted values for that field name... which are like `blue` `red`, etc.

I'm pretty sure the input recognition for autosuggest is by input name, this is why I have given each input different names that should load the autosuggest values for inputs with the same name previously used in that browser.

When I don't load it programatically, it renders and shows me the previously searched terms for that input name. Browser autosuggest, works fine then.

How do I get this result when appending inputs to the page programatically? Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: it might be a security measure to lessen xss vectors, or it might just be something done at page load and not tried again. maybe you can hard-code the inputs and then append them with jq when needed.

Comment: That's what I figured.. Guess we can't use javascript for everything lol

Comment: Well if you really need it, you could record the keystrokes/ submits and auto suggest them next time. If its heavy on ur db, use nosql/file storage n clean them regularly. ;)